# How to Autowire a Spring DataTablesRepository in a Spring @Controller class?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to incorporate 'spring-data-jpa-datatables' to my project from this Maven group - 'com.github.darrachequesne'
However the server is throwing a Bean Creation Exception after I do my set up,

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private gov.ed.dmcs.finrec.datatable.repositories.FedGLRepository gov.ed.dmcs.finrec.rest.controllers.TransactionResearchController.fedGLRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fedGLRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#f96bd26' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#f96bd26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fedGLRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#f96bd26' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#f96bd26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:923) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:503) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#f96bd26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:637) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:449) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:577) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:267) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
... 53 more
```

Below are my Controller Class

```
@Repository("fedGLRepository")
public interface FedGLRepository extends DataTablesRepository<FedGLVariance, 
Long> {}
```

and Repository

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/inbound")
public class TransactionResearchController {

     @Autowired
     private FedGLRepository fedGLRepository;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/fedGLResults", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public DataTablesOutput<FedGLVariance> searchDMBatchSummary(@Validated 
               DataTablesInput input) throws Exception {
           return fedGLRepository.findAll(input);
     }

}
```

I also have jpa:repositories tag with package declaration of my repository in SpringApplication.xml file

```
 <jpa:repositories factory-class="org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean" base-package="gov.ed.dmcs.finrec.datatable.repositories"/>
```

Please help, thanks in Advance.

Adding pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    <jersey.version>1.18.3</jersey.version>
    <!-- <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
    <spring.version>3.2.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!-- <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
    <spring.security.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <!-- 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
         -->        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>       

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Newly added DatatablesConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = 
DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class
                    ,basePackages = "gov.ed.dmcs.finrec.datatable.repositories"
                    ,entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory"
                    ,transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerETL")
@ComponentScan({"gov.ed.dmcs.finrec.datatable.repositories"})
public class DataTablesConfiguration {

public DataTablesConfiguration() {
    super();
}
}
```

entityManagerFactory bean in spring xml file

```
<!-- Define Entity Manager Factory -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <!-- property name="persistenceXmlLocation" 
 value="classpath:persistence.xml" /--> 
  <property name="persistenceUnitName">
    <value>dmcs_JPA_ETL</value>
  </property>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean
         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <!-- property name="database">
                <value>dmcsweb</value>
            </property -->
            <property name="showSql">
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Your FedGLRepository is an interface.  Do you have an implementation of this interface?  If so,  do you have a a bean that returns your class?

Comment: @karen: According to this tutorial https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables I don't have to have an implementation for the interface

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? Which version?

Comment: @alturkovic - I am not using Spring boot, do we have to use Spring boot to use 'spring-data-jpa-datatables' ?

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` in the edit?

Comment: @alturkovic - Added pom.xml to the post

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables#troubleshooting) the version you are using (5.0.0) is not compatible with Spring 4. You should either update your Spring or downgrade the `spring-data-jpa-datatables`.

Comment: I have downgraded my spring-data-jpa-datatables to version 3.1, but now I am getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined" issue. I have edited my post, can you please help with the issue